# ai.grakn.redismock.exception.ParseErrorException

Tags: redis, mocking, vaticle-typedb

Running JUnit test of code doing jedis.get(key), via command line mvn test. The test seems to succeed, but seeing multiple stack traces from RedisServer thread. Using redis-mock 1.0.6 and jedis 2.9.0.

### In IntelliJ, setting breakpoint on the throw doesn't yield much as far as diagnostics. The server is trying to read messageInput and gets an EOFException in consumeCount. Are these errors significant? How are they caused?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" Exception in thread "Thread-5" ai.grakn.redismock.exception.ParseErrorException
    at ai.grakn.redismock.SliceParser.consumeCount(SliceParser.java:83)
    at ai.grakn.redismock.RedisCommandParser.parse(RedisCommandParser.java:27)
    at ai.grakn.redismock.RedisClient.nextCommand(RedisClient.java:69)
    at ai.grakn.redismock.RedisClient.run(RedisClient.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ai.grakn.redismock.exception.ParseErrorException
    at ai.grakn.redismock.SliceParser.consumeCount(SliceParser.java:83)
    at ai.grakn.redismock.RedisCommandParser.parse(RedisCommandParser.java:27)
    at ai.grakn.redismock.RedisClient.nextCommand(RedisClient.java:69)
    at ai.grakn.redismock.RedisClient.run(RedisClient.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exception come up when I used a single Jedis instance in multiple threads; it's not thread-safe.